# How to add a AutoGenerate riwnumber as Key column in PXProjection?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I want to add a AutoGenerate number column in PXProjection DAC?

What i want,
In PXProjection DAC, I wan to add a Field, which should generate a unique number for each row, It might be unique with the combinaion of Fields consider in Projection, How may i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure how well you understand projections, let me cover some basics as I understand them first.  A PXProjection is the xRP Framework equivalent of a SQL view.  It does not contain any actual database tables or fields but simply creates access to a "view" into the data.  As such, it does not have the ability to have a sequence, or identity, field of its own.  It does, however, require that you define the key field(s).  Once defined, you would retrieve the records of the projection as if it was its own table using reference to all of those key fields.

Here is a sample (not all fields) of one of my projections.

```
[PXProjection(typeof(
    SelectFrom<INTran>
    .LeftJoin<INLocation>
        .On<INLocation.locationID.IsEqual<INTran.locationID>>
    .LeftJoin<SOShipLine>
        .On<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr.IsEqual<INTran.sOShipmentNbr>
            .And<SOShipLine.lineNbr.IsEqual<INTran.sOShipmentLineNbr>>>
    .LeftJoin<SOLine>
        .On<SOLine.orderNbr.IsEqual<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr>
            .And<SOLine.orderType.IsEqual<SOShipLine.origOrderType>
            .And<SOLine.lineNbr.IsEqual<SOShipLine.origLineNbr>>>>
    .LeftJoin<SOOrder>
        .On<SOOrder.orderNbr.IsEqual<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr>
            .And<SOOrder.orderType.IsEqual<SOShipLine.origOrderType>>>
    .LeftJoin<ContactBAccount>
        .On<ContactBAccount.bAccountID.IsEqual<SOOrder.billContactID>>
    .LeftJoin<POReceiptLine>
        .On<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr.IsEqual<INTran.pOReceiptNbr>
            .And<POReceiptLine.lineNbr.IsEqual<INTran.pOReceiptLineNbr>>>
    .LeftJoin<POOrder>
        .On<POOrder.orderNbr.IsEqual<POReceiptLine.pONbr>
            .And<POOrder.orderType.IsEqual<POReceiptLine.pOType>>>
    ))]
[Serializable]
[PXCacheName("Transactions Projection")]
public partial class MYINTransactions : IBqlTable
{

    #region DocType
    public abstract class docType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<docType> { }
    [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true, IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(INTran.docType))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = INRegister.docType.DisplayName)]
    public virtual String DocType { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region TranType
    public abstract class tranType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<tranType> { }
    [PXDBString(3, IsFixed = true, BqlField = typeof(INTran.tranType))]
    [INTranType.List()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tran. Type")]
    public virtual String TranType { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region RefNbr
    public abstract class refNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<refNbr> { }
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(INTran.refNbr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = INRegister.refNbr.DisplayName)]
    public virtual String RefNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region LineNbr
    public abstract class lineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<lineNbr> { }
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(INTran.lineNbr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Line Number")]
    public virtual Int32? LineNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region TranDate
    public abstract class tranDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<tranDate> { }
    [PXDBDate(BqlField = typeof(INTran.tranDate))]
    public virtual DateTime? TranDate { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region InvtMult
    public abstract class invtMult : PX.Data.BQL.BqlShort.Field<invtMult> { }
    [PXDBShort(BqlField = typeof(INTran.invtMult))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Multiplier")]
    public virtual Int16? InvtMult { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region BranchID
    public abstract class branchID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<branchID> { }
    [Branch(typeof(INTran.branchID), BqlField = typeof(INTran.branchID))]
    public virtual Int32? BranchID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region InventoryID
    public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }
    [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(INTran.inventoryID))]
    public virtual Int32? InventoryID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region SubItemID
    public abstract class subItemID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<subItemID> { }
    [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(INTran.subItemID))]
    public virtual Int32? SubItemID { get; set; }
    #endregion

}
```

As you can see, it pulls data from many tables and then defines fields to be accessed via MYINTransactions and includes IsKey on the key fields and "BqlField =" to map to the related fields.  Even though we use PXDB for the field attributes, these are not actual DB fields themselves.  The PXProjectionAttribute overrides the behavior of the fields.  I believe it is possible to set properties that will enable the projection to maintain data, at which point, the PXDB type attributes should convey the applicability to the database when the SQL commands are built from BQL.  That's more advanced than I have had time to explore myself, so I won't go into any further detail there.

Now, more specifically to your question directly... Depending on how you intend to use the projection, you might define additional fields using PXDBScalar or PXFormula to populate the values, but in my attempts, this had unreliable results.  The issue for me was that I needed the values at the time of the actual SQL call, and the fields, being unbound, did not exist at the database level.  They would work on my screen, but some of my more complex BQL statements would fail because the values at the time of the SQL call were null  due to being unbound.

The best recommendation that I can make is that you use a database field in one of the base DAC's to produce the desired field and map a field in your projection to that field.  This will produce the most reliable results, should you try to use the projection in complex ways.  Alternatively, if this is for use in a GI, you can use a formula in the GI's field definition to concatenate fields, if that is your goal.